# How to turn off Google Chrome saved passwords, email autofill?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to turn off Google Chrome's saved passwords, emails or usernames?

For example, let's say I saved my Facebook credentials and now I want to turn off autofill for some time (not completely removing it from Chrome, just making the saved password temporarily unavailable). So when I turn on it again, it starts filling credentials accurately. is there any way to do that ?

Any helpful comments, answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score -1):

I get this from the FAQ, hope it helps...

Stop asking to save passwords
By default, Chrome offers to save your password. You can turn this option off or on at any time.

On your computer, open Chrome.
At the top right, click More More and then Settings.
At the bottom, click Show advanced settings.
Under "Password and forms," uncheck the box next to "Offer to save your web passwords" or "Offer to save passwords with Google Smart Lock for Passwords."
To offer to save passwords again, check the box next to "Offer to save your web passwords" or "Offer to save passwords with Google Smart Lock for Passwords."

Comment: if I saved my credentials and now I want to turn off for some time (not removed saved password ) then ?

Comment: I thinks you can activate later but I don't know if this "deletes" your data, maybe it would ask again for your credentials, so you can use it.